# Java BufferedReader for zero-terminated strings

Tags: java, bufferedinputstream, null-terminated

I need to read zero-terminated strings from InputStream in Java.

Is there similar to BufferedReader.readLine() method for reading zero-terminated strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Java doesn't recognise a zero-terminated string as such. You'll have to read the `InputStream` and look for a 0 byte.

Note that this doesn't address the issue of character-encoding. The `InputStream` will give you the stream of bytes, and you'll then have to encode to characters via a `Reader`. If you have a multi-byte character encoding then the issue becomes more complex.

Comment: If that works depends on the character encoding. Actually he needs to read from a Reader and look for a 0 character, not a 0 byte.

Comment: He explicitly asks for zero-terminated strings from the *InputStream*. It's confusing though since he then mentions BufferedReader

Comment: Since you can't read characters and strings from an InputStream, wouldn't it been nice of you to tell him that instead of confusing him with a halfway incorrect answer?

Comment: That's why a) I explicitly highlighted the 0 byte b) have clarified this following feedback. You may want to publish an answer yourself if you can produce one you're happier with.

Comment: MacGordon already did, so I don't know why I should repeat him. Actually "no" would have been a sufficient answer to Domas' question, since he just asked if there is a method similar to readLine for reading null-terminated strings.

Answer (score 8):

```
package com;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AAA {

    private static final String ENCODING = "UTF-8";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bOut.write("the first line".getBytes(ENCODING));
        bOut.write(0);
        bOut.write("the second line\r\n (long one)".getBytes(ENCODING));
        bOut.write(0);
        bOut.write("the third line".getBytes(ENCODING));
        printLines(new ByteArrayInputStream(bOut.toByteArray()));
    }

    public static void printLines(InputStream in) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(in, ENCODING);
        scanner.useDelimiter("\u0000");
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(scanner.next());
            System.out.println("--------------------------------");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This. Scanner has got to be the most under utilized `java.util.*` class.

Answer (score 1):

you will also need to understand what is that "zero" means . input/output streams deal with bytes whereas readers/writers deal with characters. if you want to match against a zero character then byte to char conversion encoding will come into play.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a method similar to the one below.  Create a `BufferedReader` from an `InputStream`. The `BufferedReader` is passed by reference so it will retain state. It could easily be stored in an instance variable as well.

```
public String readLine(BufferedReader buff) throws IOException{
    int c = buff.read();
    // if EOF
    if (c == -1){
        return null;
    }
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("");
    // Check if new line or EOF
    while (c != -1 && c != 0){
        builder.append((char) c);
        c = buff.read();
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

....

```
String line = reader.readLine(buff);
while (line != null)
{
System.out.println(line);
line = reader.readLine(someBufferedReader);

}
```

Comment: This will throw away everything after the first 0-byte to the following EOL. In case your file only contains 0-byte-delimited `String`s you’ll only get a single `String` from it.

Comment: The BufferedReader is passed by reference for the example so will keep its state. On the second call it will start where it left off.

Comment: this solution doesn't handle multibyte encoded characters. The solution of @dennis.zhdanov does.