# How should I read until \0/null with a socket?

Tags: java, sockets

I am trying to read from a socket until I reach "\0" (null). This is the terminator used by Flash. I had this problem also, in C(++).

```
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {   
    outputLine = kkp.processInput(inputLine);
    out.println(outputLine);
    if (outputLine.equals("Bye."))
    break;
}
```

This example code from the Oracle Java documentation will not work in my situation because "readLine" will only count \r\n and such. I'm not sure how to read into a buffer, I have some ideas as to how I'd do it but I'm not sure how to implement.

Comment: How does your Java code look like?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686789/java-bufferedreader-for-zero-terminated-strings

Comment: The solution @andersoj linked to in that post (the one with StringBuilder etc) isn't parsing(returning) my data until I disconnect, and then it will all come at once.

Comment: Do you control the sender side?  You sure the sending tcp stream is flushing after each line/record?   You could put in a little printf debugging to out chars one by one in the while loop to see what's going on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();

for(int b; ((b = in.read()) > 0;) {
   // do something with b.
}
// stops at end of file or b == 0.
```

Comment: but b is an integer? Surely I want the actual content?

Comment: The actual content is bytes of value 0 to 255 which you can get from the `int` The reason its not a byte is that you need an extra value `-1` for the end of stream.

Answer (score 0):

You can read individual bytes from a socket by using a [DataInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html) object.

```
DataInputStream inStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

byte next = inStream.readByte();
```